# How to run nestjs with electron?

Tags: electron, nestjs, integration

I am trying to make a desktop application with electronjs. Since nestjs makes the back-end development super-easy, I want to use it with electron.

Initially I tried to run the command

> > electron . && nest start

This makes the nest process start only after the electron app is closed.

I found only one video on youtube for this and no other proper solution elsewhere.
link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWpybfpyzPI

I was having difficulty in understanding it.

I also wanted to know the possibility of smooth communication between electron and nestjs if I am able to achieve what has been achieved in the video. It doesn't seem like a standard thing to me.

Comment: You should definatelly have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-electron-ipc-transport if you plan to go this way!

Answer (score 3):

This is not easy but not impossible as well...
I will assume that you are going to create some angular frontend application along with local nestjs api server... Then we can do this with following tricks...

1. Create electron + angular app using [xplat](https://github.com/nstudio/xplat)
2. Create your local nestjs application.
3. For production builds do the following trick..
   a) In electron index.ts file add the following may be in create window function.

   if (!serve) {
   const { fork } = require('child_process');
   const ps = fork(`${__dirname}/main.js`);
   }

   a.1) first build your Web Application.
   b) build your nestjs application and then copy nestjs node_modules plus nestjs dist into your angular dist.
   c) using electron_builder generate your packages and make sure electron builder will copy node_modules.. by default it will ignore it but we can pass some arguments to electron builder... by using package.json
   something like below...

   "files":[
   "**/*",
   {
   "from": "node_modules",
   "to": "node_modules",
   "filter": ["**/*"]
   }
   ],

Note : for serving we dont need to run nestjs in electron all we need is to serve nestjs separately...