# How to integrate Electron with Reactjs and Nestjs to create a distributable app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, nestjs, electron-forge

I'm having trouble to deploy Electron with Reactjs and Nestjs as a distributable app. I want all contained in an installer.

What I have done so far:

1- Nestjs run the command: npm run build that create a dist.
2- ReactJs with Electron: npm run make that create the installer.

What I want: create a single app that contains the back and front in the same installer. Is that possible? Please can someone help with this? I'm very desperate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496887/how-to-run-nestjs-with-electron